# Unable to install package

Tags: apt, software-installation, nginx

I'm trying to install a few packages, the command is :

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras passenger
```

But I'm getting an error afterward:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-extras : Depends: nginx-common (= 1:1.6.2-9.5.0.4~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: perl (>= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1) but 5.14.2-21+deb7u2 is to be installed
                Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
                Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-38+deb7u8 is to be installed
                Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not installable
                Depends: libperl5.18 (>= 5.18.2) but it is not installable
                Recommends: passenger (< 5.0.5) but 1:5.0.4-1~trusty1 is to be installed
 passenger : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-38+deb7u8 is to be installed
             Recommends: passenger-doc (= 1:5.0.4-1~trusty1)
             Recommends: passenger-dev (= 1:5.0.4-1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't exactly know what to do with this problem, I do believe I need to install some packages, but all of those?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I fixed it.

I guess you followed the same guide as me (https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04) and this one only works if you are using 14.04. What version and distribution are you using?. You can find it if you execute `cat /etc/*-release`.

If you look on like with VERSION, it look like this on `VERSION="7 (wheezy)"`. 
Next ting you need to do is edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list` as root. So you can to `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list` and than change

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main
```

to

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger <Your version> main
```

in my case

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger wheezy main
```

Than do `sudo apt-get update' Now you should be able to install nginx-extras passenger

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu (instead of Debian, which your answer seems to indicate), you should use the output of `lsb_release -sc`.

Comment: @muru, that is right. Still you still you can find the name in `cat /etc/*-release`

Comment: have you actually checked the value of `VERSION` on Ubuntu? Sure, the value is there, but not in that field.

Comment: yes, and there  2 names VERSION, and one is correct. And I am thankful that you made it easier for ubuntu users.